# How to select components in s4 class like components in ordinary lists?

Tags: r

in R it is possible to create a list

```
k <- list()
k[[1]] <- airquality
k[[2]] <- rock
k[[3]] <- AirPassengers
k[[4]] <- airmiles
k[[5]] <- trees
k[[6]] <- treering
```

and selecting it with

```
k[c(1:3,6)]
```

How it is possible to do same in S4 class?

for example I create the some data from dismo package:

```
library(dismo)
example(voronoi)
```

that performs following:

```
p <- matrix(c(17, 42, 85, 70, 19, 53, 26, 84, 84, 46, 48, 85, 4, 95, 48, 54, 66, 74, 50, 48, 
              28, 73, 38, 56, 43, 29, 63, 22, 46, 45, 7, 60, 46, 34, 14, 51, 70, 31, 39, 26), ncol=2)

v <- voronoi(p)
v
```

I want to select the coordinates of a polygon, it can be done with.

```
v@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords.
```

My question is How to select for example 1 to 3rd and sixth component?

my idea to use

```
v@polygons[c(1:3,6)]@Polygons[[1]]@coords
```

does not work. R says:

```
Error: trying to get slot "Polygons" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with `v@polygons[c(1:3,6)]` but rather in the attempt to apply `@Polygons[[1]]@coords` directly to the resulting list. instead, you could use `lapply()` on `v@polygons[c(1:3,6)]` like this:

```
result <- lapply(v@polygons[c(1:3,6)], function(x) x@Polygons[[1]]@coords)
```

which works as expected.

Comment: But I am still wondering why this information is not in the documentation